# Type in registry is not resolved

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following registrations:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies())
.Where(t => typeof(IReadModelService).IsAssignableFrom(t) ||
    typeof(IDatabaseRepository).IsAssignableFrom(t))
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerDependency()
.PropertiesAutowired();
```

Which registers the following type:

```
public class DeviceReadModelService : IDeviceReadModelService
{
    public DeviceReadModelService(ReadModelsSettings dd)
    { }
}
```

And this bit register an instance:

```
builder.RegisterInstance(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(configFilePath), typeof(ReadModelsSettings)))
    .As<ReadModelsSettings>();
```

And this is the issue I am having.

If I try to resolve the type ReadModelsSettings it works properly but if I try to resolve IDeviceReadModelService it fails, it basically says that ReadModelsSettings is not registered even tho I can it in the registration list.

```
container.Resolve<ReadModelsSettings>(); -- works
container.Resolve<IDeviceReadModelService>(); --fails
```

Any idea what the issue is?

**UPDATE**

Just to clear it up, it I change the implementation of DeviceReadModelService to:

```
public class DeviceReadModelService : IDeviceReadModelService
{
    public DeviceReadModelService()
    { }
}
```

Both the types are resolved.

Comment: Does manual registering work if you remove auto registering? For example, `builder.RegisterType<DeviceReadModelService>().As<IDeviceReadModelService>()`

Comment: @win if I do the manual registration it does work indeed... can't really understand what the issue is with the generic code because I still can see the types registered.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see registration for this types `DeviceReadModelService : IDeviceReadModelService`.

```
builder.RegisterType<DeviceReadModelService>().As<IDeviceRea‌​dModelService>()
```

and you can register an interface and it implemented type with your created instance.

```
public interface IReadModelsSettings { }
public class ReadModelsSettings : IReadModelsSettings { }
builder.Register<ReadModelsSettings>((c) => { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(configFilePath), typeof(ReadModelsSettings)) }).As<IReadModelsSettings>().SingleInstance();
```

and this registration is no different from manual registration

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AssemblyUtils.GetAllAssemblies())
.Where(t => typeof(IReadModelService).IsAssignableFrom(t) ||
typeof(IDatabaseRepository).IsAssignableFrom(t))
.AsImplementedInterfaces()
.InstancePerDependency()
.PropertiesAutowired();
```

Maybe this will be better

```
var assembly =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();// or your target Assembly
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
     .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository") || t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
     .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency()
     .PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: That type implements the IReadModelService interface. With my original code both the registrations are there, it just fails to revolve DeviceReadModelService if is has a constructor accepting ReadModelsSettings which is also registered, but with an empty contructor it works

Comment: where you registered IDeviceReadModelService

Comment: I just told you that with my original code everything gets registered, the problem is that the dependencies between objects are no resolve. The problem is somewhat related to lifetime scopes